# AttributeError: 'PythonOrgSearch' object has no attribute '_testMethodName'

Tags: python, selenium, attributeerror

I am trying to run this basic test case with selenium but I keep getting an AttributeError and I am not really sure on what to do.

```
import unittest 
from selenium import webdriver


class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromdriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://www.python.org")

    def test_example(self):
        print("test")
        assert True

    def not_a_test(self):
        print('this wont print')

    def tearDown(self): 
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: test_example (__main__.PythonOrgSearch)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jbene\OneDrive\Documents\Selenium\testcases\main.py", line 26, in tearDown
    self.driver.close()
AttributeError: 'PythonOrgSearch' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

I tried adding an **init** fucntion to see if it would fix the problem and it did, but then I end up getting a different AttributeError which is the reason why I am stuck.

```
import unittest 
from selenium import webdriver


class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, driver = None):      
        if driver is not None:
            self.driver = driver
        else:
            self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromdriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://www.python.org")

    def test_example(self):
        print("test")
        assert True

    def not_a_test(self):
        print('this wont print')

    def tearDown(self): 
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

this is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jbene\OneDrive\Documents\Selenium\testcases\main.py", line 29, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\unittest\main.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\unittest\main.py", line 271, in runTests
    self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\unittest\runner.py", line 184, in run
    test(result)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 84, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 122, in run
    test(result)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\unittest\case.py", line 650, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\unittest\case.py", line 569, in run
    testMethod = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
AttributeError: 'PythonOrgSearch' object has no attribute '_testMethodName'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code you provided:

The method name for setting up the test case should be **setUp()** with a capital "U". Python is case-sensitive, so the **setup()** method you defined will not be recognized as a setup method and won't be called before the test runs. Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

There is a typo in the file path for the Chrome driver. In the line where you instantiate the webdriver, you have "**chromdriver.exe**" instead of **"chromedriver.exe"**. You should correct this typo to ensure the Chrome driver is located and loaded correctly. (I'm not sure if you renamed it)

Perhaps may try this code, it works on my site:

```
import unittest 
from selenium import webdriver

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```